# Putting biographical data in order from 4 parameters using python 3.3

Tags: python, string, parameters, boolean, function

I need to create a function called student data, that takes 4 parameters, a name (a string), age (an integer), student number (a string) and whether they are enrolled in CSCA08 (a boolean), and returns a string containing that information in the following format: `[student number,name,age,enrolled]`.

I have written the following code but it doesn't work

```
def student_data(name,age,number,enrolled):
    name = str()
    age = int()
    number = int()
    enrolled = bol()
    return '['+ 'number'+','+'name'+','+'age'+','+'enrolled'+']'
```

The code should work as follows:

```
>>> student_data("Vivian",32,"1234567",False)
`[1234567,Vivian,32,False]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be this:

```
def student_data(name, age, number, enrolled):
    return str([name, age, number, enrolled])
```

The output is:

```
>>> student_data("Vivian",32,"1234567",False)
"['Vivian', 32, '1234567', False]"
```

If the `'` around the name and number are a problem you could use instead this:

```
def student_data(name, age, number, enrolled):
    return '[' + ','.join([name, str(age), number, str(enrolled)]) + ']'
```

The output is then:

```
>>> student_data("Vivian",32,"1234567",False)    
'[Vivian,32,1234567,False]'
```

Comment: def student_data(name, age, number, enrolled):
    return str([number, name, age, enrolled])

Comment: Glad to hear, that it helped. But please vote answers up if they helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is your current function:

```
def student_data(name,age,number,enrolled):
 name = str()
 age = int()
 number = int()
 enrolled = bol()
 return '['+ 'number'+','+'name'+','+'age'+','+'enrolled'+']'
```

It should be:

```
def student_data(name,age,number,enrolled):
     return '['+str(number)+','+str(name)+','+str(age)+','+str(enrolled)+']'
```

In Python, you don't need to declare that they are string , int or bool (even if you had, your current code actually overwrites the current value with an empty string/int/bool). However, to make sure that it will be possible to "add" two strings (because you can't str to bool, string to int, etc), use `str(var)` that turns the var into a string.

As number,name,age and enrolled are variables, you don't need to use quotes.

Comment: Thanks man, helped alot! All the punctuations were in order :)